# How to evaluate $\displaystyle\int_0^9\int_0^9xy\sin(xy)dydx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

So I was bored, and decided to evaluate some integrals for fun. After a while, I came up with this$$\int_0^9 \int_0^9xy\sin(xy)dydx$$which I thought that I might be able to solve. Here is my attempt at doing so:

We can rewrite this as$$\int_0^9x\int_0^9y\sin(xy)dydx$$and then as$$\int_0^9\dfrac{\sin(9x)-9x\cos(9x)}xdx\\=\int_0^9\dfrac{\sin(9x)}xdx-9\int_0^9\cos(9x)dx$$which I know that$$-9\int_0^9\cos(9x)dx=-\sin(81)$$but I'm not sure how to evaluate$$\int_0^9\dfrac{\sin(9x)}xdx$$although I probably could use IBP, however my question is

#### How do I evaluate $\displaystyle\int_0^9 \int_0^9xy\sin(xy)dydx$?

Comment: So both integrals' limits are $\;0,\,9\;$ ? So you are integrating on a square of side $\;9\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio Oh crap, I forgot to write it as $\iint_{[0,9]^2}$ whoops I'll edit that

Comment: @ScipioAemilianus Well, the actual value of that integral is *not* $\;\frac\pi2\;$, though it is close to that. It'd be that if the upper limit were infinity, but it isn't. The actual value is $\;Si(81)\sim 1.56\;$

Comment: @DonAntonio So the value of my double integral would come out to exactly $\operatorname{Si}(81)-\sin(81)\approx0.57362$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could rewrite your last integral as $$\int_0^{81}\frac{\sin x}xdx=\text{Si}(81)$$After substituting $u=9x$. So the answer is simply $\text{Si}(81)-\sin(81)$